# Seeing the Prophet in My Dreams and making Dua to the Prophet

Tags: dua, prophets, dream

As'Salam Wa'lakum

My Dream of the Prophet, peace and blessings be upon him,

please forgive me for this long description of the dream I had, but I am doing it for my own benefit so inshallah I don't forget this beautiful dream.

I had a dream a few years ago (maybe 4 years) that I still remember and I want to recall it for as long as possible.

I felt like I was at a boarding school, and it was in the evening. I went outside to see an Imam (Sheikh) whom I can no longer picture, but I felt that I knew this person (who may not have actually been an imam in real life).

I can remember that my feeling prior to seeing the imam was a happy (possibly exciting) feeling. As I approached him, he told me that the Prophet, may peace and blessings be upon him, had been dead for 2 weeks, and there is no one here that can help us. (I felt that we needed to move the unburied Prophet, may peace and blessings be upon him, but we were stranded or possibly helpless.)

We were facing the Prophet, and we were standing approximately 20 meters away from him. It is important to mention that I could not see the Prophet as he was in a casket (plain box). I remembered at that point, I became anxious and somewhat helpless. I asked the Imam (Sheikh), "Can I see the Prophet (may peace and blessings be upon him)?" He turned to me and said, "You can, but you have to kiss him." At that point, I felt a fear almost as though I didn’t want to kiss a dead person, and I think I had felt that I didn’t really want to do that.

At that moment, the Prophet's (PBUH) left hand hand rose to the air (and there was a scar on his left hand) as though he was being resurrected, and that part of his hand had yet to heal. At that moment, I felt something that I had never felt in my life—an overwhelming excitement and love that I cannot describe and certainly cannot do justice to. I ran without any hesitation and started to kiss the Prophets (peace be upon him) hand, at that point I remember seeing his face.

The features I can certainly remember were he had fair skin (lighter side than dark), and I distinctly remember his eyes were small, smaller than average. His beard was not long and not short.

As I was kissing his hand, I did not say Salams; I said, "Ahlan bikum ya Rasul Allah." (I remember because I have never said those words in this life to anyone.) They are not foreign to me, but they are not words that I would have used. I then made dua in front of him and said, "Ya Allah, grant me paradise," but the Prophet, may peace and blessings be upon him, did not reply. I then made another dua straight after with minmum pause; I know I said either of these two things: I either said, "Ya Allah, grant my family (eayilati) paradise," or "Ya Allah, grant my parents (aaheli) paradise."

At that point, the Prophet, may peace and blessings be upon him, replied with "ameen." My feelings of happiness were still there, and I must emphasize that I cannot describe the feeling that I had, but it was like I felt the top of my head tingling (strange, I know, but I cannot describe the feeling I had).

I then returned to the Imam/Sheikh and asked him why hasn’t anyone come (my feelings turning to frustration). I do not remember a reply. I remember saying to him again, "We must tell them the Prophet is here!" (My feelings turned to anger.) Surely, they will come! (as in surely they will drop everything and gather to gether to help.)
Looking towards the distance.

And that is all I can remember from my dream.

My overall feelings towards the dream was happiness that I seen the prophet may peace and blessings be upon him. I felt the dream was a positive dream. And it certainly brought happiness to me.

However as I think about this dream, I feel that it maybe a warning to me. That he did not reply with ameen when I made dua “ya allah grant me paradise”.. I think about this particular moment a lot. And I wonderer.

I should also mention that it not seem like a long pause between my first and second dua, or at least I hope it wasn’t.

my mother died from cancer (may Allah grant her paradise) 1 or 2 years  after that dream.
I remember telling my mother that dream (may Allah grant her paradise). And she was so happy she started crying.

Comment: Dream interpretation is off-topic.

Answer (score -1):

I am also a cancer patient. But no matter whatever trials we face in our life, we should pray only to Allah.

> And who could be more astray than those who call upon others besides
> Allah—˹others˺ that cannot respond to them until the Day of Judgment,
> and are ˹even˺ unaware of their calls? [Quran 46:5](https://quran.com/46/5)

> When the Prophet (ﷺ) visited any ailing member of his family, he would
> touch the sick person with his right hand and would supplicate:
> "Allahumma Rabban-nasi, adhhibil-ba'sa, washfi, Antash-Shafi, la
> shifa'a illa shifa'uka, shifaan la yughadiru saqaman [O Allah! the
> Rubb of mankind! Remove this disease and cure (him or her)! You are
> the Great Curer. There is no cure but through You, which leaves behind
> no disease]." https://sunnah.com/riyadussalihin:902